# AWS Athena query "table" createtime

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to find a way to query the createtime and other such properties of the table that athena can see from my glue catalog.  I tried SHOW TABLES FROM  and it only showed me the table names.

Is is possible to query the table properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
describe formatted <table_name>
```

Comment: It works, but now that I have looked at the problem to solve it won't get me what I ultimately need.  I didn't think about the fact I have to get multiple tables from the schema.  Appreciate it though.